# MySql query with limit showing one less element

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a php file which generates a webshop layout.The problem is when I started to split the products to pages. I have the following query wich runs in the products database where every kind of product can be found. There is a prodducttype column which specifies under which menu it should be displayed.
The query

```
$sql = "SELECT id,descr, nm, img, price FROM c1640644.products WHERE 
producttype = '".$GLOBALS["useableproductid"]."' LIMIT ".($start-    1).",".$stop;
```

There is one row which always missing
I used echo to display the query just before running it its the following:

```
SELECT id,descr, nm, img, price FROM c1640644.products WHERE 
producttype = 'laptop' LIMIT 0,8
```

Briefly about the database:
Currently 3 types of products laptops, headphones, desktops.
When displaying laptops they are from ID 1- 17 and ID=1 is missing. Headphones from ID 18-22 and ID=21 is missing. Desktops from ID 23-27 and ID=23 is missing. Always the same products are missing.

The displaying method is:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 echo $row["nm"]; //just an example echo in the code it gets displayed with design
  ...
}
```

Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless, and tables with names like c1640644 are often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: I'll do the order thank you! The c1640644 is because its a university server where c1640644 is my student number.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then

Comment: It's amazingly similar to my student number (a while ago). Weird.

Comment: Your display method is fine, your select statement is throwing you off here. Why do you use LIMIT 0,8? Do you want to display up to 8 items per page or something like that?  Have you tried using just `LIMIT 8`?

Comment: But in looking at your question again, it's not always the first item in the series that is missing. You say that from 18 to 22, id 21 is the one missing. That's weird. No leading or trailing spaces in the producttype field in those rows, right?

Comment: sql queries are not ordered so you have to use an order by id (for example) - otherwise the same query could potentially return different results every time you run it. Second: first page is LIMIT 0, 8 then second page? LIMIT 8, 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reasonable explanation for the observed behavior ("missing" row for `'laptop'` and a "missing" row for `'headphone'`) is that the rows do not satisfy the predicate, equality comparison to producttype.  (This assumes there are fewer than `$stop-$start` rows is being returned.

I'd verify the values of producttype.

```
SELECT producttype, COUNT(1)
  FROM c1640644.products
 GROUP BY producttype
 ORDER BY producttype
```

Is the count returned equal to the number of rows you expect to be returned? In particular, I'd look for values that are visually close to "laptop", but would not satisfy an equality match, such as `'laptop ultra-portable'`, or `'lapt0p'`. Those values would not satisfy an equality comparison to `'laptop'`.

---

Without an `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL is free to return rows in any order. The result from the query with the `LIMIT` clause is indeterminate. It's possible that a query with `LIMIT 0,8` and `LIMIT 8,16` may include the same row. It's also possible that a row will be "skipped".

If the case is that there is always "one row missing", I'm suspicious that there's a fetch before the `while` loop. The loop shown in the question looks right. It's also possible that `nm` column contains an empty string, and it makes it look like a row is "skipped". For debugging that, consider including `echo "row fetched";` as the first line inside the loop. Or initializing a counter variable before the loop `$i=0;`, and then inside the loop, increment `$i` and include `$i` in the string that in the debug output.